# Get an element that might be a children from next element

Tags: jquery, selector

Suppose that I want to select the nearest target element from `startFromThis` (only the element that come after `startFromThis`. the target might be a child of any unnamed or unclassed element. Is there anyway to select this.

Sorry, i would like to edit startFromThis to be an ID

```
<div id="startFromThis"><div>
<div>
  <span class="target"></span>
<div>
```

Comment: Will there be multiple divs with class *startFromThis*?

Comment: sorry, i edit that to use id already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#startFromThis').closest('target element')` assuming `startFromThis` is an id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.startFromThis').closest('.target').html('Selected!');
});
```

Check out the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".startFromThis").closest().children(".target");
```